# Phase-spectrum: $arg(\cdot)$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, signal-processing

I came to this frequency spectrum for a signal $h_1[n]$:

\begin{align*}
H_1(e^{j\theta}) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h_1[n] \cdot e^{-j\theta} \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (0.3 \cdot \delta[n] + 0.6 \cdot \delta[n-1] + 0.3 \cdot \delta[n-2]) \cdot e^{-j\theta} \\
&= \ldots \\
&= 0.6 e^{-j\theta} \cdot (1 + cos(\theta) )
\end{align*}

I also have the magnitude spectrum:

\begin{align*}
|H_1(e^{j\theta})| &= |0.6 e^{-j\theta} \cdot (1 + cos(\theta) )| \\
&= 0.6 \cdot \underbrace{|e^{j\theta}|}_\text{$=1$} \cdot |(1 + cos(\theta))| \\
&= 0.6 \cdot |(1 +  cos(\theta))| \geq 0 && \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

And now I am supposed to give the [phase spectrum of this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%28%200.6%20e%5E%7B-i%20%5Ctheta%7D%20%281%20%2B%20cos%28%5Ctheta%29%20%29%20%29). My problem is that I don't know how this $arg(\cdot)$ function works here. For

\begin{align*}
arg( 0.6 e^{-i \theta} (1 + cos(\theta) ) ) &= -2 \theta - arg( 0.6 e^{-i \theta} (1 + cos(\theta) ) )
\end{align*}

Could somebody explain this to me?

E.g. why is for:

\begin{align*}
H_1(e^{j\theta}) &= 0.5 + 0.86 \cdot cos(\theta)
\end{align*}

The $arg(\cdot)$:

\begin{align*}
arg(H_1(e^{j\theta})) &= - 2 \theta - arg(0.5 + 0.86 \cdot cos(\theta))
\end{align*}

Comment: When multiplying terms in the complex field, their arguments are added together. Since $\cos(x) \in [-1,+1]$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $(1+\cos(\theta))$ is a non-negative real number, which always has an argument of zero. This is also true for $0.6$. Thus, adding the arguments together gives $0 + -\theta + 0 = -\theta$. The wolfram plot shows this function modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Hi! What exactly do you mean by "* which always has an argument of zero*"? I have extended my question a little with another small example. Could you provide an answer explaining this?

Comment: Complex numbers can always be written as $A e^{i\phi}$, where $A$ is the magnitude and $\phi$ the argument. For a non-negative real number $x$, we have that $A = x$ and $\phi = 0$, that is, $A \cdot e^{i\phi} = x \cdot 1 = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly computed the complex frequency response as

$$H(e^{j\theta})=0.6(1+\cos(\theta))e^{-j\theta}\tag{1}$$

This is exactly in the form

$$|H(e^{j\theta})|e^{j\phi(\theta)}\tag{2}$$

where $\phi(\theta)$ is the desired phase function, because, as you've noted yourself,

$$0.6(1+\cos(\theta))\ge 0$$

so it qualifies as the magnitude of $H(e^{j\theta})$. Comparing (1) and (2) gives

$$\phi(\theta)=-\theta\tag{3}$$

so the phase is linear, which is also obvious from the symmetry of the sequence $h[n]$.

Comment: Hi! That makes sense, I think now I see it. But what I still don't understand is how For

\begin{align*}
H_1(e^{j\theta}) &= 0.5 + 0.86 \cdot cos(\theta)
\end{align*}

The $arg(\cdot)$ is:

\begin{align*}
arg(H_1(e^{j\theta})) &= - 2 \theta - arg(0.5 + 0.86 \cdot cos(\theta))
\end{align*}

This still looks odd to me .. Could this be wrong?

Comment: @StefanFalk: This is wrong. In this case $H_1(e^{j\theta})$ is real-valued, so its argument can only be either $0$ or $\pi$ (mod $2\pi$). So for values of $\theta$ for which the expression is positive, the argument is $0$, and for values of $\theta$ for which it becomes negative, the argument is $\pi$.